# Are there lists for magic spells where I can base my spells on?

Tags: magic, warfare, fantasy-races, worldbuilding-resources

Are there lists for magic spells where I can base my spells on? I found a site long ago but I can't find it anymore when I was about to use it on my story. Is there anything you can recommend where I can base any kinds of magic spell chants?

Comment: You can base your magic spells on almost any list if you want any kinds. Take this wikpeida article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lists_of_lists . You will find the entry "Lists of academic journals". You can now create a spell that gives you a list of academic journals if you so desire

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE *rekt*! Good to see you made your way here. I added the [tag:worldbuilding-resources] tag as you are looking for an external list, which is fine with this tag, but not without it (yes, we can be weird at first, but long lists could get endlessly expanded, which makes it basically impossible to define a "best" answer). I'd *recommend* to remove the *recommend* part from your question (that invites opinions without any basis) and instead write what the magic spells need as characteristics. Do you need rituals, words, gestures, ... that fit your humans, orcs, ...?

Comment: You can [edit] your question with the little hyperlink at the end of your post that says "edit". It would also be nice to point out whether you are looking for books or online sources. For example the game *Dungeons and Dragons* has extensive lists of spells - most of which do not explicitly mention which kind of words are needed if any words are needed at all. But it would give you an idea of how such lists could be composed. Do you need a description of magical effects, of components needed, of words that are used, of rituals that must be performed, of participants that must be present, ...

Comment: https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of places really, here is a spell list of the DnD 5e spells for example:

https://donjon.bin.sh/5e/spells/

Here is a list with the spells and charms and what not from Harry Potter:

http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_spells

The thing is, you will be able to find dozens upon dozens of these lists online. If you are worried by copyright infringements and the like, look for more occult works. And read through them, many of them go on about spells, rituals and the like.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries, with slight modifications to root words.

Most of the strategies for generating your own magic words involve manipulating root words into a similar style. Harry Potter for instance:. Lumos = light spell like luminosity. Leviosa for levitate/levity.

So the only list you really need is a dictionary if you want to go that route. A couple linguistic texts might help you manipulate the roots in a common way. Shifting a romance language towards Slavic phoneme structure, for instance.

You don't need to use standard dictionaries either. You could use scientific jargon or common slang (Urban dictionary) to find your words of power.

It's all make believe, so there isn't a right answer, but this is a strategy that tends to work and doesn't run afoul of ip law.